# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'path' must be a string or Uint8Array without null bytes when running Gulp with VueJS

Tags: vue.js, gulp, rollup

I inherited of a VueJS project which builds assets using GulpJS.

I have been struggling for a while now to deal with the VueJs components and I am now facing this issue:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'path' must be a string or Uint8Array without null bytes. Received '\x00commonjs-proxy:/home/xxx/Sites/xxx/node_modules/lodash/package.json'
at Object.readFile (fs.js:343:10)
at next (/home/xxx/Sites/xxx/node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-resolve/node_modules/browser-resolve/index.js:98:12)
at load_shims (/home/xxx/Sites/xxx/node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-resolve/node_modules/browser-resolve/index.js:116:7)
at resolve (/home/xxx/Sites/xxx/node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-resolve/node_modules/browser-resolve/index.js:236:5)
at /home/xxx/Sites/xxx/node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-resolve/dist/rollup-plugin-node-resolve.cjs.js:55:5
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at resolveId$1 (/home/xxx/Sites/xxx/node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-resolve/dist/rollup-plugin-node-resolve.cjs.js:54:11)
at /home/xxx/Sites/xxx/node_modules/rollup-stream/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:1610:32 {
```

code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE'

Here are the versions of what I think is relevant here (I know a lot could be updated but I don't have the budget to do this, I would just like to get this running again):

- node 14
- Gulp 4.0.2
- rollup-stream 1.14
- rollup-plugin-vue 2.2.8
- rollup-plugin-buble 0.14.0
- rollup-plugin-node-resolve 2.0.0
- rollup-plugin-commonjs 5.0.5
- rollup-plugin-node-globals 1.0.9
- rollup-plugin-uglify 1.0.1
- vue 2.2.4

My Gulp task is as follows:

```
function js(cb) {
  rollup({
    entry: JS_FILE,
    format: 'iife',
    sourceMap: !isProduction(),
    useStrict: false,
    plugins: [
      vue({
        css: COMPONENTS_DIRECT_CSS_FILE
      }),
      buble({
        objectAssign: 'Object.assign'
      }),
      resolve({
        jsnext: true,
        main: true,
        browser: true,
        preferBuiltins: false
      }),
      commonjs({
        include: 'node_modules/**'
      }),
      nodeGlobals(),
      (isProduction() && uglify())
    ]
  })
  .on('error', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (isProduction()) {
      // kill the build process
      process.exit(1);
    } else {
      this.emit('end');
    }
  })
  .pipe(source('index.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(JS_DESTINATION));

  cb();
}
```

I have no idea how to debug this further. Any help would be appreciated.